# how to pass variables between functions in a class, while defining them as an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, object, oop

```
class C():
    def A(self):
        mm=[]
        kk=[]
        x="Y"
        while x=="Y":
            x=input("do you have any stuff?[Y/N]: ")
            if x=="N":
                break
            mm.append(input("enter the name of the thing: "))
            kk.append(input("Enter the value of the thing: "))
     def printing(self):
        print("="*100)
        print("stuff")
        for i in range(0,len(self.mm)):
            print(self.mm[i]," "*20,self.kk[i])
shr = C()
shr.A()
shr.printing()
```

The code gives out an attribute error,
'C' object has no attribute 'mm'
does anyone know how to resolve this error ?

Comment: ... you **never** assign an attribute `self.mm` in your class.. why do you *expect* there to be such an attribute? If you expect there to be an attribute on that instance, you *must* assign to `self.mm` somewhere...

Comment: Don't use `()` when defining classes . Refer https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax

Comment: @ZalakBhalani I agree, it is ugly, but it is not invalid and to be clear, not the source of this error

Comment: Note that it is generally best practice to get user input *separately* and then *pass it in* to the class when instantiating it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree with you, but it is not good practice. And I am not saying that this is a source of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need class fields, you have to put them inside `__init__` method.
in your case you should do it this way:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mm = []
        self.kk = []
    def A(self):
        x="Y"
        while x=="Y":
            x=input("do you have any stuff?[Y/N]: ")
            if x=="N":
                break
            self.mm.append(input("enter the name of the thing: "))
            self.kk.append(input("Enter the value of the thing: "))
     def printing(self):
        print("="*100)
        print("stuff")
        for i in range(0,len(self.mm)):
            print(self.mm[i]," "*20,self.kk[i])
shr = C()
shr.A()
shr.printing()
```

Comment: The don't *have* to be in `__init__`. While this is generally a best practice, you should be clear that it isn't the crux of the issue

Answer (score -1):

You can create variables inside `__init__`. This variable, called the *instance variables*, belong to the object instance. The `__init__` method is similar to constructors in C++ and Java.

Example 1

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mm = []
        self.kk = []
        self.x = 'Y'
        
    def A(self):
        while self.x == "Y":
            self.x=input("do you have any stuff?[Y/N]: ")
            if self.x=="N":
                break
            self.mm.append(input("enter the name of the thing: "))
            self.kk.append(input("Enter the value of the thing: "))
            
    def printing(self):
        print("="*100)
        print("stuff")
        for i in range(0,len(self.mm)):
            print(self.mm[i]," "*20,self.kk[i])
```

You can also create variables outside the `__init__` class. These are, in fact, *static class variables* and are, therefore, accessible to all instances of the class. They can be read through a class reference (e.g: `ClassName.varname`) and can be set from any method by prefacing with the class name (`Classname.varname= X`)

It can be read via `self.varname`, as well, producing the same value for all instances. However, when assigned a value via an instance reference (as in `self.varname = X`) a new `self.varname` will be created for that instance only, obscuring the class variable.

Example 2:

```
class C:
    mm = []
    kk = []
    x = 'Y'
        
    def A(self):
        while self.x == "Y":
            self.x=input("do you have any stuff?[Y/N]: ")
            if self.x=="N":
                break
            self.mm.append(input("enter the name of the thing: "))
            self.kk.append(input("Enter the value of the thing: "))
            
    def printing(self):
        print("="*100)
        print("stuff")
        for i in range(0,len(self.mm)):
            print(self.mm[i]," "*20,self.kk[i])
```

Comment: calling this "outside `__init__`" is misleading. These are variables defined in the class body. The OP doesn't actually do that anyway, the create *local* variables.

Comment: Can you please reword the introduction paragraph? This is *extremely* misleading. Setting attributes and setting variables are two different things unrelated to the location of the assignment. While one *commonly* does one in ``__init__`` and the other "outside", that is not the cause of their effect.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have edited my submission. Apologies for the previous wordings as I agree that they were extremely misleading. Thank you for pointing it out.